# Spring Data JPA circular reference in getting SesionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to start a Spring Project, and I've made all the configurations, however, whenever I try to start it, I get the following error message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Below are the files I'm using for this

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class WestworldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WestworldApplication.class, args);
        RegisterRobot re = new RegisterRobot();

    }
}
```

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }
}
```

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Ommited password for safety reasons

Comment: As of hibernate 5.3 the `SessionFactory` IS the `EntityManagerFactory`. (`SessionFactory` in fact now extends `EntityManagerFactory`. So by defining this bean, you actually defined your own `EntityManagerFactory`, Spring Boot backs of and you run into a cycle. However generally you shouldn't be using the `SessionFactory` but just plain JPA.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm a begginer to this, what do you mean by just plain JPA?

Comment: Use the `EntityManager` instead of hibernate `Session` and `SessionFactory`.